# "That is an interesting question." vs "It is an interesting question, that."

Tags: word-usage, writing-style, phrase-usage

I am not a native English speaker and I tend to construct sentences like "It is an interesting question, that.". My girlfriend who is a native English speaker always tells me that I am talking like yoda everytime I construct such kind of sentences. So I wonder if grammatically speaking sentences of the type just mentioned are correct or not. I guess it could also be that it is just a matter of style. I think I have seen this pattern of sentences in some academic books, specially from the 90's.
So my doubt is essentially whether the two following sentences are both grammatically correct.

> (1) That is an interesting question.
>
> (2) It is an interesting question, that.

Based on some comments, I think it might be helpful to know that I am a Spanish native speaker, and in Spanish such pattern of sentences are common too. So I guess my Spanish could be interferring with my English usage.

Comment: I don't think you'd have seen things like your example #2 in "academic books" - it's very much a ***colloquial spoken usage*** to "reduplicate" the pronominal reference *(**it, that**)* in this way. Compare the structurally similar form ***I'm** a Brit, **me**.*

Comment: I've seen it in fiction, especially, I'm thinking, British fiction or fiction that is trying to mimic upper-class speech.  There's nothing wrong with it, but it's not idiomatic in the US.

Comment: Personally, I think *I'm lower-class, me* sounds far more likely than *I'm upper-class, me.* But I'm certainly on board with the idea that *I'm British, me* is more likely than *I'm American, me*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers   I didn't have any idea that sentences like "It is an interesting question, that." sound like the way upper-class people talk. I am a native Spanisch speaker person and in Spanish sentence in these pattern sound so natural. So I guess my Spanish could be overlapping with my usage of English.

Comment: The construction in _It's an interesting question, that_ is called [Right-Dislocation](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/167283/15299). Left-Dislocation would be [something like _That question, it's an interesting one._](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/320063/15299).

Comment: @JohnLawler, that is quite helpful, thanks a lot!

Comment: There's also ***That's** an interesting question, **is that***. Which again I'd say is very much an ***informal / spoken*** (stereotypically, often "dialectal, uneducated") usage, not something you'd expect to find in academic texts.

Comment: But that's got an extra verb, like a tag question. Different rule, different construction.

Comment: @John: My first thought was the repetition of the verb hardly makes any difference, present or not. Then I thought of things like *They're a funny family, **they are*** - which sounds perfectly natural to me, as does *They're a funny family, **them***. But  *They're a funny family, **are they*** sounds ***really*** weird.

Comment: "That's an interesting question" would probably be used 85% of the time by educated Anglophones. '_That_ is an interesting question!" perhaps 10% of the time, usually with the stress indicated, to convey the importance of the matter and appreciation for the question-raiser's perceptiveness. "It's an interesting question, that" perhaps 2% of the time, showing reflection on the issue. "It is an interesting question, that" perhaps never (mixed registers). (Don't forget "_Interesting question!_")

Answer (score -3):

In Linguistics, ending a phrase with a preposition is called "preposition stranding" (Ex. *Winning the lottery is something to be delighted about* VS *Something to be delighted about is winning the lottery*).

Purists tend to reject it, as they do with "split infinitives" (*It is better to drive carefully especially in urban areas* VS *It is better to carefully drive especially in urban areas*... or *To go boldly where no man has been before* VS *To boldly go where no man has been before*) and "double negation" (Standard British English: *I bought nothing at the market* VS Western Irish English(possibly): *I didn't buy nothing at the market*).

However, it occurs more and more frequently today, especially in spoken English but also in written English. It sounds more informal and laid-back, and so it is acceptable in these contexts.

Comment: 'That' is not a preposition.